# Trouble with Operator Overloading and the *this Pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operator-overloading, this

I'm working on operator overloading for a self made dynamic array class. I'm also trying to learn how to use the *this pointer but it's not going so well. Below are the parts of the class and my code that I thought were needed to explain the issue.

**I don't understand why I can't call a member function on the *this pointer when the *this pointer is pointing to the left side of the + equation.**

### Here is the stub driver that is calling the + operator:

<< and >> are already overloaded and working.

```
cout << "Please enter a word to add:";
    string theWord;
    cin >> theWord;
    //add word
    array1 = array1 + theWord;
    cout << "array1: " << array1 << endl;
```

### Here is the main code:

```
class DynamicArray
{
public:
    //constructor
    DynamicArray(int initialcapacity = 10);
    //copy constructor
    DynamicArray(const DynamicArray& rhs);
    //destructor
    ~DynamicArray();

    //operator+ - add a string
    DynamicArray operator+(const string& rhs) const;

    //operator+ - concatenate another DynamicArray
    DynamicArray operator+(const DynamicArray& rhs) const;

    //change the capacity of the DynamicArray to the newCapacity - 
    //  may reduce the size of the array - entries past newCapacity will be lost
    void resize(int newCapacity);

private:
    string* mWords;//pointer to dynamic array of strings
    int mNumWords;//the current number of words being kept in the dynamic array
    int mCapacity;//the current capacity of the dynamic array (how many strings could fit in the array)

    //display all the contained strings (each on a newline) to the output stream provided
    void displayContents(ostream& output) const;

    //add all the strings contained in the input stream to the dynamic array - resize if necessary
    //return how many words are added to the array
    int addWords(ifstream &input);

    //add a single word to the dynamic array - resize if necessary
    void addWord(const string& word);

};

//add a single word to the dynamic array - resize if necessary
void DynamicArray::addWord(const string& word)
{
    if (mNumWords >= mCapacity)//need more space?
    {
        resize(mCapacity + 1);
    }

    mWords[mNumWords] = word;
    mNumWords++;
}
```

### This is the function I'm currently working on

```
//operator+ - add a string
DynamicArray DynamicArray::operator+(const string& rhs) const
{
    //this doesn't work, why doesn't it, how should/do I use the
    //this pointer properly
    this.addWord(rhs);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Since `this` is a pointer, use the `->` notation, like:  `this->addWord(rhs);`.

Comment: Silly mistake using the . instead of ->. But that still doesn't work. It looks like what Paul below said about addWord not being a const function is the problem. I'll have to write my own instead of calling addWord()

Comment: Do not "write your own instead of calling addWord()".  Instead, invest the time in writing an operator += that takes a string.  You will then be "killing two birds with one stone".  You would now have 1) an operator += that makes sense and, 2) your operator + becomes a simple function (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using *this.*  instead of *this->*, you have defined operator+ as a const member function.  This means that no members can be mutated, and no calls to non-const member function functions are to be performed.  Your addword function is non-const.  That's the reason for the error -- you are violating const correctness.

Also, why are you mutating the array for merely calling operator + in your code?  That operator shouldn't need to change any aspect of the current object.  I can understand operator += mutating the object, but not operator +.

What you should do is write an operator += first.  This operator can mutate the current object, since that is the semantics of += (change the current object).  Then operator + can be written this way:

```
//operator+ - add a string
DynamicArray DynamicArray::operator+(const string& rhs) const
{
    DynamicArray temp = *this;
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

This is assuming you have a working copy constructor.  In the example above, you are mutating a temporary, calling += on the temporary, and returning the temporary.  The *this* object does not change.

Here is what your operator += should look like:

```
DynamicArray& DynamicArray::operator+=(const string& rhs) 
{
    this.addWord(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Now operator += becomes non-const because the intention of += is to change the current object.  Note that the return value is a reference to the current object.  This now works in concert with the operator + above.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the const part. Wouldn't I have to mutate the array to add a word to it?

Comment: "No" to the question concerning mutation.  Look at simple addition using ints.  `a = b + c;`  If a, b, and c are integers, do b and c change in that example?  Of course not.  Objects should behave the same way.

Comment: I do not have a working constructor that takes std::string and I don't need a += because I was going to overload the + operator again but it would take a DynamicArray as its argument. What about something like this:

`if (mNumWords < mCapacity)`
  `mWords[mNumWords] = rhs;`

Comment: See my updated answer.  That is all you need for a working operator +=.  Besides, if I see a class with operator +, why can't I also have operator +=?

Comment: Wouldn't += take another DynamicArray as an argument which means you couldn't pass in a string?

Comment: Look at your current public interface.  You have a public operator + that takes a string.  I would expect that there would be a public operator += that takes a string.  Otherwise, how would I, as a user of your class, able to append a string onto the current array?  `DynamicArray a; string s = "abc"; a += s;`  I want to do that.

Comment: The + operator is appending a string to the end of the array, in that case the += operator is redundant no?

Comment: It is not redundant.  There is a fundamental difference between operator + and operator +=.  Please see the code above in my answer.  If it were redundant, why do classes such as std::string have both an operator + and operator +=?  Why not just operator +?  And please, see the use case above in my comment previously.  How can I accomplish this with your current class?

Comment: Also, you can overload operator += to take a DynamicArray reference and do basically what operator += did in the code above.  The real goal in my stating that you should have an operator += is that a programmer using a class such as yours expects that operator+= is available due to the availability of operator +.  Also, if there is a template class or other code that handles classes with the addition operators defined, your class can be used within that code without getting compilation errors ("operator += is not defined" or something similar to that).

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+` has to be non-const since you want to change the state of the object on each it is invoked. Also you don't have to write

```
this->addWord( rhs);  // correct but not needed
```

because use of method inside a class member function is called on `this`  pointer implicitly. Given this, you may write:

```
DynamicArray DynamicArray::operator+(const string& rhs)
{
    addWord( rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

You can also implement this operator as `void`:

```
void DynamicArray::operator+(const string& rhs)
{
    addWord( rhs);
}
```

and use it this way:

```
array1 + theWord;
```